# Proof Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence ${x_n},x_n = n^{1/3}$

a) Show that for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there is $n_0$such that for all $n\ge n_0 , |x_{n+1}-x_n|\lt\varepsilon $?

Sol:
$|(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}|$=$\frac {n+1-n}{(n+1)^{2/3} +((n+1)(n))^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}$$\lt \frac{1}{n^{2/3}}\lt \varepsilon$

$n\gt \varepsilon^{3/2}$
Choose  $n_0\ge \varepsilon^{3/2}$

I use this formal$ (a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Can proof  this Cauchy seq. by this way

Thanks

Comment: A sequence  $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy iff $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup \{|x_n-x_m|: m>n\}=0.$ It is not sufficient that $\lim_{n\to \infty}|x_n-x_{n+1}|=0.$... A Cauchy sequence of real numbers will converge to a member of $\Bbb R. $ .....The sequence $x_n=n^{1/3}$ does not converge to a member of $ \Bbb R.$ ... E.g.$ x_{(n^3)}=n.$

Comment: I know  that seq.$x_n=n^1/3$ is not  cauchy  seq.  beacaus  is not bounded and not convergence but|(n+1)^1/3-n^1/3| in the question it must  prove to be a cauchy .

Comment: OK but that is not what's written.  The first line defines the sequence $x_n=n^{1/3}$ and the last line says " this ... sequence" but does say that you mean the sequence $y_n=x_{n+1}-x_n.$  You have correctly shown that $|y_n|<n^{-2/3},$ so you have $|y_n-y_m|\leq |y_n|+|y_m|\leq 2(\min (n,m))^{-2/3},$ so $y_n$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof for

"for any $ \varepsilon >0$ there is $n_0$ such that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\lt\varepsilon$ for $n \ge n_0$"

is correct.

But $(x_n)$ is not Cauchy, since $(x_n)$ is unbounded.